# Why is this python generator returning the same value everytime?

Tags: python, generator, yield

I have this generator that yields lists:

```
def gen():
    state = [None]

    for i in range(5):
        state[0] = i
        yield state
```

And here's the output, when I call it:

```
>>> list(gen())
[[4], [4], [4], [4], [4]]
```

Why are all the elements `[4]`? Shouldn't it be `[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are reusing the same list object. Your generator returns the one object over and over again, manipulating it as it goes, but any other references to it see those same changes:

```
>>> r = list(gen())
>>> r
[[4], [4], [4], [4], [4]]
>>> r[0] is r[1]
True
>>> r[0][0] = 42
>>> r
[[42], [42], [42], [42], [42]]
```

Yield a *copy* of the list or create a new fresh  list object instead of manipulating one.

```
def gen_copy():
    state = [None]

    for i in range(5):
        state[0] = i
        yield state.copy()  # <- copy

def gen_new():
    for i in range(5):
        state = [i]  # <- new list object every iteration
        yield state
```

Comment: Any clue why https://youtu.be/QksUFT2Cmlo?list=PLhTjy8cBISEqkN-5Ku_kXG4QW33sxQo0t&t=305 is not facing the same issue? I wrote the same code but faced the issue mentioned in the question...

Comment: @ParthKapadia scrapy almost certainly clones the item each time it’s yielded.

Comment: @ParthKapadia scrapy even [defines copy methods on the Item class](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/item.py#L114-L120) for this.

Answer (score 5):

You are `yielding` the same `list/object` so you always see the last values added to the list. You should yield a copy:

```
yield state.copy()
```

Or create the list inside the first loop:

```
for i in range(5):
    state = [i]
```

It would be as easy to create a new list/object each time:

```
def gen():
    for i in range(5):
        state = [None]
        state[0] = i
        yield state
```