# Python force variable to don't be passed by reference

Tags: python, list, dictionary, reference, append

Python dictionnary is passed by reference into list when declared out from scope, with using `a.append(b)`. For example, the following code :

```
my_dict = {}
my_list = []

for i in range(3):
    my_dict['id'] = str(i)
    my_list.append(my_dict)
    
my_list
```

return :

```
[{'id': '2'}, {'id': '2'}, {'id': '2'}]
```

how can I pass it by copying in a pythonic way, without declaring it into the for loop ? How to force a variable to don't be an object reference, **without recreating it** ?

Comment: Create the dict inside the loop or just append a dict literal.

Comment: The same answers as to this question apply here: [Why is this python generator returning the same value everytime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687185/why-is-this-python-generator-returning-the-same-value-everytime)

Answer (score 1):

You have one and only one dict, and you keep overwriting its key `id`, create the dict in the loop

```
my_list = []
for i in range(3):
    my_dict = {}
    my_dict['id'] = str(i)
    my_list.append(my_dict) # can shorten in my_list.append({'id' : str(i)})
```

---

Can be shorten with a list comprehension

```
my_list = [{'id' : str(i)} for i in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**concept** :

list stores the reference to the object (`my_dict`), so whenever you change anything inside the `my_dict` same will be reflected in your list (`my_list`)

**Code:**

```py
my_list = []

for i in range(3):
    my_list.append({'id' : str(i + 1)})
    
print(my_list)
```

output:

```
[{'id': '1'}, {'id': '2'}, {'id': '3'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```py
my_list = []

for i in range(1, 4): # If you put range(3), you'll get [{'id': '0'}, {'id': '1'}, {'id': '2'}]
    my_dict = {}
    my_dict['id'] = str(i)
    my_list.append(my_dict)
    
print(my_list)
```

A shorter way could be:

```py
my_list = []

for i in range(1, 4):
    my_list.append({'id' : str(i)})

print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, dictionaries are passed by reference; all objects are in Python. Laterals are passed by value of course.

The code can work as expected if you append the dictionary directly into the list like this:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(3):
    my_list.append({'id': str(i)})
```

Can be improved as @Yusef Maali suggested:

```
my_list = [{'id' : str(i)} for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

The `my_dict` instance is declared and assigned outside of the for loop, so you are adding to `my_list` the same instance of the dictionary.

You need to create a new instance of the dictionary for every loop:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(3):
    my_dict = {}
    my_dict['id'] = str(i)
    my_list.append(my_dict)
```

this code has many possible way to be optimized:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(3):
    my_list.append({'id': str(i)})
```

and the best pythonic way is list comprehension:

```
my_list = [{'id' : str(i)} for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: `my_list = [{'id' : str(i)} for i in range(3)]` . missing `}`

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = []

for i in range(0,3):

    my_dict = {} # making dictionary every time when running the loop.

    my_dict['id'] = str(i) # assigning value

    my_list.append(my_dict) #appending in list
    
my_list
```