# Make a list of lists where the last value of list is incremented

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I want to make a list of lists where each sublist will have its second value greater than the second value of its predecessor.
e.g.
my list_of_lists = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4],...]

I thought this would do it but I can't see why it is not appending the correct current version of the list.

I would like to thank Scott and gionni for the work they put in helping me to understand why my attempt was wrong and the key role object references make in this.

**Code**

```
mylist = [1,1]
mylist_of_lists = []
for i in list(range(1,11,1)):
    print("i: ", i)
    mylist[1] = i
    print("mylist : ", mylist)
    mylist_of_lists.append(mylist)
    print("mylist_of_lists : ", mylist_of_lists)
print(mylist_of_lists)
```

**Console return**

```
i:  1
mylist :  [1, 1]
mylist_of_lists :  [[1, 1]]
i:  2
mylist :  [1, 2]
mylist_of_lists :  [[1, 2], [1, 2]]
i:  3
mylist :  [1, 3]
mylist_of_lists :  [[1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3]]
i:  4
mylist :  [1, 4]
mylist_of_lists :  [[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4]]
i:  5
mylist :  [1, 5]
mylist_of_lists :  [[1, 5], [1, 5], [1, 5], [1, 5], [1, 5]]
i:  6
mylist :  [1, 6]
mylist_of_lists :  [[1, 6], [1, 6], [1, 6], [1, 6], [1, 6], [1, 6]]
i:  7
mylist :  [1, 7]
mylist_of_lists :  [[1, 7], [1, 7], [1, 7], [1, 7], [1, 7], [1, 7], [1, 7]]
i:  8
mylist :  [1, 8]
mylist_of_lists :  [[1, 8], [1, 8], [1, 8], [1, 8], [1, 8], [1, 8], [1, 8], [1, 8]]
i:  9
mylist :  [1, 9]
mylist_of_lists :  [[1, 9], [1, 9], [1, 9], [1, 9], [1, 9], [1, 9], [1, 9], [1, 9], [1, 9]]
i:  10
mylist :  [1, 10]
mylist_of_lists :  [[1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 10]]
[[1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 10]]
```

**Desired output**

my list_of_lists = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4],...]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this python generator returning the same value everytime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687185/why-is-this-python-generator-returning-the-same-value-everytime)

Comment: Hi gionni, it might do, I think I have to study yields first as I couldn't get any of the functions on that answer to do anything.

Comment: The generator is not important, what matters is the explanation of references

Comment: Hi gionni, so my list of lists was really something like [[ref to mylist], [ref to mylist]...] and each time mylist was being updated that update was passed to each list in the list of lists as those sublists were having the same reference updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Occam's Razor: the reason they all look the same is that they all *are* the same.

You need to create a new list for each call to `append` to add (for example, `append([mylist[0],i])`).

Comment: Hi Scott, I don't understand how a list in my list_of_lists is getting overwritten by the next iteration of the list, or the new call you mention. Apologies, I just don't understand that.

Comment: It is not being *overwritten*; you are appending references to the same list (`mylist`) each time, which is why when you change it all the sublists in `mylist_of_lists` change accordingly.  Instead, you need to make a new list for each call to `append`.

Comment: Hi Scott, I understand references, but (please excuse scant knowledge here) I thought my list_of_lists was being updated each time by the appending of the new list. From what I can tell I need to understand yield and generators to do this.

When you say "a new list for each call to append" I am not sure what you mean, does that mean a new name for the list of lists or a new name for the my list? I'm sorry, I know how frustrating it is explaining things to some one who isn't getting it, apologies.

Comment: Please see edited answer.  This has *nothing* to do with `yield` or generators.

Comment: Hi Scott, when I was updating mylist by mylist[1] = I did that mean that each instance of my list in the list of lists was having that update?

Comment: I added these two lines to the for loop to try to understand the answer (which works).     print("mylist id: ", id(mylist))
    print("***** ", id([mylist[0],i]))
id(mylist) is the same reference each time as you said, but [mylist[0],I] had a new id each time. Is that because you were making a  new list object by using [mylist[0],I]?

Comment: For anyone who doesn't understand the references this helped me
https://programmerall.com/article/4286501147/